Homogeneity of Stone-Cech compactification
A topological space $X$ is said to be $\textit{homogeneous}$ if to every pair of points $p$ and $q$ of $X$, there exists at least one homeomorphism of $X$ which carries $p$ to $q$.
Suppose $\beta X$ exists.

What can we say about the homogeneity of $\beta X$ if $X$ is homogeneous?


Also, what about the converse?


Is the converse really that easy? Notice if $p,q\in X$ and $\gamma:\beta X\cong\beta X$ takes $\eta p$ to $\eta q$, $\eta:X\to\beta X$ being the canonical map (which, by the way, always exists for any space!) then it is not a priori obvious that $\gamma$ would restrict to an automorphism of $X$. $\eta$ does not even always inject...

In any case it would be worth adding any context you might have. I suspect this could be quite a hard problem in generality

The countably infinite discrete space $\omega$ is homogeneous, but $\beta \omega$  is not homogeneous, and not even $\beta \omega\setminus \omega$ is homogeneous.

@FShrike Now that you have pointed it out, I found the ambiguity in my argument. Yes it seems a hard one too.

@AlexKruckman Is this a result of Walter Rudin? Do you have any shorter proof?

The fact that $\beta\omega$ is not homogeneous is easy, since every point in $\omega$ is isolated, but no point in $\beta\omega\setminus \omega$ is isolated. For non-homogeneity of $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$, one has to work harder. Walter Rudin showed that P-points and non-P-points always live in different orbits. But it is consistent with ZFC that there are no P-points - Rudin used CH to construct P-points. The non-homogeneity in ZFC is due to Frolik: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1967-73-01/S0002-9904-1967-11653-7/S0002-9904-1967-11653-7.pdf
